# Storing verifaction code

Tags: java, spring, email-validation

I am building a web app which runs react on the front end and Java/Spring on the back end.
I am using a RESTful API to communicate with my client (client will communicate with an external API too).

I am facing a problem. When a user registers, I want to send an email verification code. My question is about practice.

- Is it ok to send an email with a verification code, store the code in the database and then check if the code is correct?
- Or is it better to create some static bean which would hold the code for a while and then check if it's correct?

I am not sure which is better in terms of back-end logic.

I appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very common practice to store this in the DB. Just make sure to cleanup the expired tokens once in a while (maybe on timer, maybe when inserting new ones).
You can also store the tokens in an in-memory cache (`EhCahe` comes to mind) and set the expiration time accordingly, but this way you lose the cache if the application shuts down. Yes, you can make the cache persistent, but why not go the DB route then?

With that said, think about not storing the token anywhere and instead send the link with the email as an URL parameter and a salted hash as an additional parameter. Once the link is clicked, you can check if the hash matches and if it does, the email parameter wasn't tempered with, so you can mark it as validated. Maybe not Pentagon-level secure, but probably enough for email validation and makes everything easier.
In pseudo-code:

```
public String hash(String email) {
    MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digester.update(email.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    digester.update("RanDOmComplCatEdSalt647826583745".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digester.digest());
}

String email = "dude@example.com";
sendEmailWithLink("/verify?email=" + email + "&hash=" + hash(email));
```

On the way in, you just do the exact same thing to calculate and check if the hash matched:

```
String email = httpRequest.getParameter("email");
String receivedHash = httpRequest.getParameter("hash");
if (hash(email).equals(receivedHash)) {
   //the user didn't do anything funny, mark email as valid
}
```

Or, taking this idea further but with more security, you can generate something like a JWT that contains the email and is properly encrypted.